# How to close the internal member nav bar in the top of the code editor?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-assist

After install visual assist x in vs2010. I think the internal member nav bar in code editor is no need.

Answer (score 0):

Use the IDE options dialog to turn off the navigation bar - either for all languages or just for specific languages.

`Tools | Options | Text Editor | All Languages (or specific language) | Display: Navigation Bar`